# if variable part changes in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to have a variable where only a part of it is changing?
I have a scale that gives me a value 6 times a second. Every time the weight on the scale changes, it gives me a value like `$r00000`  or `4$00400`. But if the value stays constant for 1 sec it returns `$b01234`. 
My problem is that I can't find a way to use the "$b" in an `if` statement, so that after $b I have a value that changes.

```
Dim MyString, MyArray, i
Dim test
MyString = Scale_Value
If MyString="*$b**????***" Then
    MyArray = Split(MyString, "$b", -1, 1) 
    For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        test =   (MyArray(i))
        tmpPWgt = (CStr(Mid(test, 1,1) & "." & Mid(test, 2)))
    Next
Else
    tmpPWgt="0.000"
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried using `InStr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
If Left(MyString, 2) = "$b" Then
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be interested in the $b values only, use Left() and Mid() to get the parts for each input:

```
>> a = Split("$r00000 $b01234 4$00400 $b54321 $r55555")
>> for each m in a
>>     WScript.Echo "----", m
>>     if "$b" = Left(m, 2) Then
>>        m = CLng(Mid(m, 3))
>>        WScript.Echo "1 sec w:", m
>>     end if
>> next
>>
---- $r00000
---- $b01234
1 sec w: 1234
---- 4$00400
---- $b54321
1 sec w: 54321
---- $r55555
>>
```